# Isomorphism of $M$ and $\hom_R(R,M)$ if $R$ is not commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am reading Jacobson's Basic Algebra II, page 159.
Here's what he wrote: (here $R$ denotes a ring which is not necissarily commutative)

> We now consider an arbitrary $R$-module $M$. We have the isomorphism of $M$ onto $\hom_R(R,M)$ which maps an element $x\in M$ into the homomorphism $f_x$ such that $1\mapsto x$. This is an R-isomorphism if we make $\hom_R(R,M)$ into a right $R$-module as in Proposition 3.4 by defining $fa$, $a\in R$, by $(fa) (b) = f (ab)$.

Where I cannot understand is that $M$ is a left $R$-module but $\hom_R(R,M)$ is a right $R$-module;
how can they be $R$-isomorphic?

I had already searched on the internet;
however, most previous questions about $M\cong\hom_R(R,M)$ seems to have an assumption that $R$ is commutative.

Since this is an important step for the following discussion in the book, I am really curious about the answer.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $R$ is not commutative then $fa$ is not necessarily a homomorphism.

Comment: Oh! Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $M$ is a *left* $R$-module, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ is also a *left* $R$-module defining $rf \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$, for $r \in R$ and $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$, by $$\forall x \in R \quad (rf)(x) = f(xr).$$
- If $M$ is a *right* $R$-module, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ is also a *right* $R$-module defining $fr \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$, for $r \in R$ and $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$, by $$\forall x \in R \quad (fr)(x) = f(rx).$$

In any case, the functions
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M) & \longrightarrow M & M & \longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M) \\
f & \longmapsto f(1) & m & \longmapsto (1 \mapsto m)
\end{align*}$$
are $R$-module homomorphisms (prove that), and they’re inverses.